# Почему не работает .submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
 function validate_form ( )
{
 valid = true;
 $('input').each(function () {
  if ( $(this).val() == "" ){
   valid = false;
   if ($(this).hasClass("error")==false) 
    $(this).addClass("error");
   
  }else{
   if ($(this).hasClass("error")) 
    valid=false;
  }
 })
   
 return valid;
}
$(".button").click(function(){
  //on('click', function(e) {
  
 
  if (validate_form() ) { // проверка на валидность
   //$(this).closest("form").submit(); // и так не работает
   
   console.log("submit");
   $("#reg_form")[0].submit();
   return false;
  }else{
   //$(".checkbox.required").addClass("error").next(".checkbox-custom").addClass("error");
  }
  
 });
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/registration/" name="regform" id="reg_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input size="30" type="text" name="REGISTER_N" value=""/>
   <input size="30" type="text" name="REGISTER_S" value=""/>
   <input type="button" class="button"  value="Зарегистрироваться" />
</form>
```

Вопрос, почему не работает.... submit и как исправить?
ошибки в консоли нет.

```js
$("#reg_form").submit(
    function () {
     console.log("Send");
     return false;
    }
   );
```

```
слово "Send не пишет в консоль"...
```

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
  //on('click', function(e) {
  
 
  if (validate_form() ){  // проверка на валидность
   //$(this).closest("form").submit(); // и так не работает
   
   console.log("submit");//пишет
   $("#reg_form").submit(
    function () {
     console.log("Send"); //не пишет
     return false;
    }
   );
   return false;
  }else{
   //$(".checkbox.required").addClass("error").next(".checkbox-custom").addClass("error");
  }
  
 });
```

[image]
пробовала дебажить.

Comment: А где сама функция validate_form() ?

Comment: я писала,по возможности, короткий код. 
а если убрать эту функцию,почему -тогда не отправляется?

Comment: У вас нет открывающей фигурной скобки после if (validate_form() )

Comment: @I2banners, простите, отпечатка, добавила функцию, мало ли что...

Прошу прощения, может я, я сразу плохо оформила код,и поэтому коротко написала, теперь я добавила validate_form,подскажите,пож-ста...

Comment: и открывающая фиг скобка в настоящем коде присутствует...

Comment: Ну мы то не знаем что присутствует. А jquery присутствует? Я проверил ваш скрипт без validate_form() все работает

Comment: присутствует... прощу прощения...

Comment: у меня даже не заходит  в .submit
(см. скриншот, когда отлаживаешь..) с чем это мб связано?.
спасибо за ответ...

Comment: @Flambo Что демонстрируют эти два фрагмента кода? Какого поведения Вы пытаетесь достичь?

Comment: я хочу проверить на заполненность всех полей,и отправить форму.

или данный код-яваскрипт работает только с аяксом?

Comment: Если не выполнять код внутри submit() то сама форма отправляется вполне нормально, если правильно jquery подключен. Аякса тут никакого нет.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот так будет работать. Добавил немного комментариев.

```js
function validate_form() {
  valid = true;
  $('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      valid = false;
      if ($(this).hasClass("error") == false)
        $(this).addClass("error");

    } else {
      if ($(this).hasClass("error"))
        valid = false;
    }
  })

  return valid;
}


$("#reg_form").submit(function(event) {
  /* Проверяем на валидность */
  if (validate_form()) {
    console.log("send");
    /* Если валидно выполняем код сверху и останавливает работу функции */
    return;
  }
  /* Выполнится только если невалидно */
  console.log("Невалидно");
  $(".checkbox.required").addClass("error").next(".checkbox-custom").addClass("error");
  /* event.preventDefault(); останавливает отправку */
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="/registration/" name="regform" id="reg_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input size="30" type="text" name="REGISTER_N" value="" />
  <input size="30" type="text" name="REGISTER_S" value="" />
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Зарегистрироваться" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`type="submit"` нужно добавить в `input`.